# I want to create a bean and make it alive when service is up (Context of 2 components)

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Actually two components are interdependent.

*1st service* is dependent on *2nd service*: I will bring up 1st  service when 2nd is down; then, after, I will bring up *1st service* too. Here, when I hit an API call I am geeting below error (as per my understanding `bean` is not geeting initialized:

```
.org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.itemfield.ws_api.wsdl.ContentMasterService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
Dependency annotations:    
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="cmWebservice"), 
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy(value=true)}
```

Comment: Any code to share?

Comment: Here we are using external URLs to get some data and whatever the bean i am trying to intialize it is getting initialized in 1st component but when i bring up 2nd component it is throwing above metioned exception here my bean could not able to initialize both components are interdependent